# Can you tell me another solution to put a line of text at the bottom of a page?

Tags: macros

I am writing a document class in which I want to put a line of text at the bottom of the text area, after the footnotes so that its place is always completely fixed. A solution for this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\title{A sample title}
\author{John Doe}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\begin{figure}[!b]
\copyright\ 2022 John Doe \hfill Department of Mathematics
\end{figure}
\par
\vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

But for some reasons, I don't want to use a float environment. Can you suggest me another solution (preferably without loading extra packages)?

Comment: More likely than not, the suggestion would depend on what your "some reason" is.

Comment: TikZ has some functionalities for absolute positioning, for one.

Comment: If there's a line of text at the bottom of the page, where is the page number supposed to go?

Comment: One option I use is to define `\cfoot` for the first page. Code [here](https://github.com/Teddy-van-Jerry/SEU-ML-Assign_LaTeX_Template/blob/96e888d28248224909e3d9e19109810fa5a2e139/seu-ml-assign.cls#L284-L302). I also add additional space for the foot line text use  `\enlargethispage`.

Comment: @Mico The same place it is now. I don't want to change its place.

Comment: @user202729 Because sometimes it moves a little:-)

Comment: Hope `Ulrich` suggestion match with your requirement...

Answer (score 3):

There are possibilities for doing absolute positioning of text on a page.
E.g., tikz provides means for doing this.

---

If a recent LaTeX release is in use where shipout-hooks are available, you can add code to the hook `shipout/foreground`.

The hook `shipout/foreground` refers to a picture-environment with top-left-corner (0,0) on the top-left corner of the page and unitlength 1pt.
(For things to occur on the page, y-/second components of coordinates needs to be negative. With a recent LaTeX-release within a `picture`-environment caring about normalizing `\dimexpr` and length-registers to `\unitlength` is not needed as it is done automatically.)

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A sample title}
\author{John Doe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
% If you want this on the titlepage only, use \AddToHookNext instead of \AddToHook
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
  \put(\dimexpr 1in+\ifodd\thepage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi\relax,
       \foo{\dimexpr-\paperheight+.5\dimexpr\paperheight-(1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip)+\ht\strutbox\relax\relax})%
  {%
    \hbox to\textwidth{\copyright\ 2022 John Doe \hfill Department of Mathematics}%
  }%
}
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If a LaTeX-release not that recent is in use, consider loading the package **eso-pic**:

The code below provides an example where the command `\AddToShipOutPicture` of the package **eso-pic** is combined with a picture-environment
wherein the command `\put` can be used for positioning text.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,eso-pic}
\title{A sample title}
\author{John Doe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ConvertToUnitlength[1]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr#1*65536/\number\dimexpr\unitlength\relax\relax
}%
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
% If you want this on every page, use \AddToShipoutPicture.
% If you want this on the title-page only, use \AddToShipoutPicture*.
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \vbox to \paperheight{%
    \hsize=\paperwidth
    %----------------------------------------------------
    %       Within the \vbox do whatever you like:
    %       e.g., use a picture-environment:
    %----------------------------------------------------
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
    \begin{picture}(\ConvertToUnitlength{\paperwidth},
                    \ConvertToUnitlength{\paperheight})(0,0)%
      % Inside this picture 0,0 is the bottom left corner.
      % Unit is cm.
      % If you wish to use length-parameter or \dimexppr, you can use \ConvertToUnitlength.
      % With recent LaTeX \ConvertToUnitlength is not really needed, but
      % you can use it for hiding ( and ) belonging to a \dimexpr
      % from the scanning for a )-delimiter of a \put-command.
      % You can also use eso-pic's \LenToUnit for this purpose.
      % If you need to learn about length-parameters of page-layout, see the documentation of the package "layout".
      \put(\ConvertToUnitlength{\dimexpr 1in+\ifodd\thepage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi\relax},
           \ConvertToUnitlength{.5\dimexpr\paperheight-(1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip)+\ht\strutbox\relax})%
      {%
        \hbox to\textwidth{\copyright\ 2022 John Doe \hfill Department of Mathematics}%
      }%
    \end{picture}%
    %----------------------------------------------------
  }%
}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage

Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you like crude hacks and if the text is to occur only on the title-page, and the title-page in any case contains footnotes so that the rule separating main text from footnotes is drawn, and you finish the title-page via `\newpage`, you can use `\footnotetext` right before `\newpage` for placing a last "footnote" holding your copyright-notice. If hyperref is in use, things need to be wrapped into a `NoHyper`-environment. I don't know how this interacts with `\raggedbottom`/`\flushbottom`.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}
\title{A sample title}
\author{John Doe}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
\vskip 1em%
{\large \@date}%
\end{center}%
% If you want this on every page, use \AddToShipoutPicture.
% If you want this on the title-page only, use \AddToShipoutPicture*.
\par
\vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\noindent#1}%
\begin{NoHyper}%
\footnotetext{\par\vspace*{\dimexpr\footskip-2\baselineskip\relax}{\normalsize\copyright\ 2022 John Doe \hfill Department of Mathematics}}%
\end{NoHyper}%
\endgroup
\newpage

Text goes here\footnote{A footnote} and\footnote{Another footnote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]